# Predictive prefix disappeared on Input of negative double in argument of dynamically allocated memory

Tags: java, oop, input, arguments, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an allocated variable e3 from class Employee that accepts 2 strings (firstname, lastname), and a double. The challenge I have encountered is that I am inserting a '-' minus sign into the double argument, when it only expects doubles.

I am using Visual Studio Code as my IDE and it labels the arguments of the dynamic memory to let you know what exactly the value of that argument is going to.

When I run my code, it outputs just fine to the screen, but in more complicated projects I believe I will need to do some type of conversion. I am looking for any suggestion regarding input of non-integer/double data into an integer/double argument. An explanation on why the predictive prefix disappears will also work!

Below I have attached my code, the first block is main(), and the second block is my class.

```
public class EmployeeTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Employee e1 = new Employee(nameF: "nameF", nameL: "nameL", monthlySalary: 2500.00);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(nameF: "nameF", nameL: "nameL", monthlySalary: 3600.75);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(nameF: "nameF", nameL: "nameL", -6000.00);
        System.out.println(e1);
        System.out.println(e2);
        System.out.println(e3);
    }
}
```

In this snippet, you can see on line 1-2 that in new Employee(), my IDE has labeled the arguments with a nameF:, nameL:, and monthlySalary:

on line 3, the monthlySalary: is omitted when I insert the '-' minus sign.

below is my Employee class file

```
public class Employee {

    private String nameF;
    private String nameL;
    private double monthlySalary;

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        firstName = nameF;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        lastName = nameL;
    }

    public void setMonthlySalary(double salary) {
        salary = monthlySalary;
    }

    public int getFirstName() {
        return nameF;
    }

    public int getLastName() {
        return nameL;
    }

    public double getMonthlySalary() {
        return monthlySalary;
    }

    //Here is the method I am having trouble with, specifically the double argument

    Employee(String nameF, String nameL, double monthlySalary) {
        this.nameF = nameF;
        this.nameL = nameL;
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }
```

[Visual Studio Code interpretation of dynamic allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSFqy.png)

Comment: I don't understand what problem you are having. Those parameter names are just displayed by your IDE, they are not part of the Java language, and have absolutely **no** effect on what your program does.

Comment: my "problem" isn't necessarily a problem of syntax, but of understanding how the compiler knows that the minus sign '-' is implying that the double being taken in is a negative value. In my mind, it sees the minus sign as a non-numerical value.

Comment: "In my mind, it sees the minus sign as a non-numerical value". I don't understand why you think this, but I can assure you that the compiler understands that the `-` indicates a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. The parameter inlay hints do not work on negative numbers. Probably because it's not treating negative numbers as literals. One workaround however is that if you switch the parameter inlay hints for your specific language to "all" then it also becomes available for negative numbers. But the downside is that it will also then be enabled for variable name parameters as well.

So, if that isn't an issue for you, then you can enable inlay hints for all types of parameters by Going to vscode settings (ctrl+,)
search for "parameter name"
scroll until you find `{language} > inlay hints > Parameter Names : Enabled` and then select `all` from the `dropdown`